# Does $\{\chi_{[n, n+1]}\}$ converge to $0$ in measure?

Tags: real-analysis

Does $\{\chi_{[n, n+1]}\}$ converge to $0$ in measure?

I want to determine if it does or not using the definition  of convergence in (Lebesgue) measure, which is:

> $f_{n} \to  f$ in measure as $n \to \infty$ if for any $\epsilon > 0$,
> $$m(\{x \in \mathbb{R} \mid |f_{n}(x)-f(x)|>\epsilon\}) \to 0
>  \;\text{as}\; n \to  \infty$$

To me it seems that the answer should be yes because given any $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\epsilon >0$, we can find some $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $x \notin [n, n+1]$  for all $n \ge N$. Then the measure of the set $\{x \in \mathbb{R} \mid |\chi_{[n,n+1]}|>\epsilon\}$ is zero as $n \to  \infty$. Am I right?

Comment: What your analysis shows is convergence almost everywhere, not convergence in measure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $0 < \epsilon < 1$, then the set $\{x \in \mathbb{R} \mid |f_n(x) - f(x)| > \epsilon\}$ is simply $[n, n+1]$, since $|f_n(x)-f(x)| = \chi_{[n, n+1]}(x)$. The question boils down to whether $m([n, n+1]) \to 0$ holds (which it does not).

Comment: Thank you, you're right. The sequence doesn't converge to $0$.

Answer (score 3):

Under the definition given in the OP $\mathbb{1}_{[n,n+1]}$ does not converge to $0$ in probability (relative to the Lebesgue measure) since for any $0<\varepsilon<1$, $m(\mathbb{1}_{[n,n+1]}>\varepsilon)=m([n,n+1])=1$.

The definition if convergence in measure given in the OP is not useful when the underlaying measure space is infite, that is when $(X,\mathscr{B},\mu)$ is a measure space and $\mu(X)=\infty$. A more useful notion of convergence in measure is the following:

Suppose $(X,\mathcal{B},\mu)$ is a measure space. A sequence $f_n$ of measurable functions converges in measure to another function $f$ if for any set $A\in\mathcal{B}$ of finite measure and any $\varepsilon>0$
$$\mu(A\cap\{|f_n-f|>\varepsilon)\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}0$$

**Remarks:**

- Under this *local* version of convergence in measure the sequence in the OP does converge to $0$ due to the regularity of the Lebesgue measure.
- The *local* version of convergence in measure given here coincides with the usual one given in probability courses.